# I really have a confusion about till where does the 1st quadrant graph go on till it changes slope

Tags: thermodynamics

I understood that the 4th quad graph would continue in a straight line along the x axis….but where does it rise again? I couldnt analyse it according to the information given. Does it just require experimental data which I need to search?[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the graph, we can tell that to bring $m$ gram of ice from $-40^\text{o}\text{C}$ to $0^\text{o}\text{C}$ we require $ 3\text{ kcal}$  of heat. This along with the fact that the specific heat of ice $s_\text{ice}\approx0.5\text{ cal}(\text{g }^\text{o}\text{C})^{-1}$ can be used to find the mass of ice in the mixture.

$$Q=ms(\Delta T)\implies m_{\text{ice}}=150\text{ g}$$

Now, the heat required to melt $150\text{ g}$ of ice can be found by using the fact that the latent heat of ice is given as $L_\text{ice}\approx 80 \text{ cal g}^{-1}$.
$$Q_\text{melt}=m_\text{ice}L_\text{ice}=1.2\text{ kcal}$$

So, the horizontal portion of the graph continues for $1.2\text{ kcal}$ along the x-axis, after which it rises again.